# Xorg and setting mouse properties

Tags: mouse, gnome, xorg

I bought myself a Logitech Trackman Marble Mouse and found some information about how to configure the buttons.  I settled on the following configuration:

```
xinput set-button-map "Logitech USB Trackball" 1 9 3 4 5 6 7 8 2
xinput set-int-prop "Logitech USB Trackball" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Button" 8 8
xinput set-int-prop "Logitech USB Trackball" "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 8 1
xinput set-prop "Logitech USB Trackball" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes" 6 7 4 5
```

Then I tried to translate this to Xorg config (`/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-marblemouse.conf`):

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Marble Mouse"
        MatchProduct "Logitech USB Trackball"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"

        Option "Floating" "off"
        Option "Buttons" "9"
        Option "ButtonMapping" "1 9 3 4 5 6 7 8 2"
        Option "EmulateWheelButton" "8"
        Option "EmulateWheel" "on"
        Option "YAxisMapping" "4 5"
        Option "XAxisMapping" "6 7"
EndSection
```

From this configuration everything takes effect *except the wheel emulation*!  After logging in:

```
% xinput list-props Logitech\ USB\ Trackball|grep "(294)"
        Evdev Wheel Emulation (294):    0
```

As far as I can see the configuration *should* be correct, is it?

Could Gnome, my DE of choice be interfering with my X config?

I've also noticed that jumping to console and back resets the wheel emulation to 0.